# Add multiple buttons in Data grid view

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpf-controls

I needed to add multiple buttons inside a single column in data grid view in WPF Application! In windows form application it could be able to do like this .
That data grid view will load from DB. At same time  , there will be 2 command buttons need to be added in each row[image]

please anyone provide a way to accomplish this!

Thank you

Comment: Your question is more like a homework question. The way to do this is already available in MSDN Library. You should search the answer first in MSDN Library of WPF documentation first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include those 2 buttons in a stack panel to achieve what you want to get. See below code sample.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2 Button Column" Width="200">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Button Name="Button1" Content="Button1" />
                 <Button Name="Button2" Content="Button2" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```